# How to save 2 models associated with one another at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a controller, which should perform an operation on 2 models, where the 2nd database model must contain the 1st models `_id` as a reference in it.

**Example:**

```
const model1 = await new firstModel(somedata).save();

const model2 = new secondModel({
    test: true //dummy
    referId: //this must contain the value of _id of model1
});

await model2.save()
```

I don't want to use `pre('save', ..)` hook. Is there any way to perform this operation?

Comment: If you're saving them together is there a reason they can't exist in the same collection?

Your firstModel schema could just use the secondModel schema.

If you're going to be saving them at the same time, every time why do they need to be separate?

Comment: I have to use 1st model for some other purpose, it would be better if the data on `model 2 ` doesnt come in a way of ` model 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preassign your own ObjectID `_id` field to your `somedata` of first model, and assign it to the second model.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
const somedata = {
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  present: true //dummy
}
const model1 = await new firstModel(somedata).save();

const model2 = new secondModel({
    test: true //dummy
    referId: somedata._id
});

await model2.save()
```

The `_id` key is optional - it is autogenerated if not passed, and accepted if passed to model constructor.